# Error in use in dialog to read XML in file client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I need to read XML content from a XML file to HTML.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="fileImport" name="fileImport" />
```

Javascript:

```
        $("#fileImport").change(function () {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            var src = $("#fileImport").val();

            xmlhttp.open("GET", src, false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlText = xmlhttp.response;
            alert(xmlText);
        });
```

But, for example, if the user selects the file `c:/q/r/ff.xml` I get `C:\fakepath\ff.xml`.

Comment: are you talking about a file upload using ajax? Also, you don't need to do the ajax call by hand, just use what already exist: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I don't wont to send file to server I need the xml to client side.

Comment: If I manually fill this var src it works well